# Read the array values by key in object return from a custom js file using nodejs file system

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript, javascript-objects

I have a config file which has the following format from a file:

```
    define([], function () {
        return {
            productItems: {
                item1: ['Apple', 'Ball', 'Car'],
                item2: ['Dog', 'Elephant', 'Frog'],
                item3: ['Goat', 'Hotel', 'Indian']
            },
        };
    });
```

I have tried JSON.parse() and unfortunately it does not read or not parsing, might be because of the wrong format.

I also used the File System module but I cannot get the proper values with the following code:

```
const getProductItems = () => {
      if (fs.existsSync(configPath)) {
        const fileData = fs.readFileSync(configPath, 'utf8');

        const productItems= fileData.match(/productItems: {(\s+.+\s+)+}/);
    
        return productItems;
     }
    }

    console.log(getProductItems);
```

It only returned the function and not the values. How am I going to get the item1, item2 and item3 values out of this custom js file?

Comment: This looks like an older module system, something like RequireJS, AMD or UMD: https://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#amd

Answer (score 0):

You can load AMD modules using [requirejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/requirejs).

This assumes the code you provided is stored in a file called *config.amd.js*

```
const requirejs = require('requirejs');

requirejs(['config.amd.js'], data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

It is asynchronous so you need to handle callbacks in the usual way.

---

An alternative approach, which is probably less reliable, would be to strip off the AMD syntax using regular expressions and then run the remaining code through a JSON5 parser.

```js
const JSON5 = require('json5');
const { readFile } = require('node:fs/promises');
const { resolve } = require('node:path');

const strip = amd => {
    const noStart = amd.replace(/^(?:.*)return/s, '');
    const noEnd = noStart.replace(/;\s*\}\s*\)\s*;\s*$/s, '');
    return noEnd;
};

readFile(resolve(__dirname, 'config.amd.js'), 'utf-8')
    .then(strip)
    .then(string => JSON5.parse(string))
    .then(result => console.log(result));
```

This seems to work with your code, but isn't suitable as a generic AMD module parser.

---

That said, I strongly recommend rewriting the config file to use JSON or be a CommonJS or ECMAScript module. AMD is sufficiently unusual it will probably be a maintenance issue going forward (as new people have to maintain the code and also won't recognise the format).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I understood correctly, but the main problem why you are not getting the data is beacuse for that you will need to call function define(), so that returns the data you need, the better approach for this is if you are willing to change your configuration, so you just make it like this

```
productItems: {
            item1: ['Apple', 'Ball', 'Car'],
            item2: ['Dog', 'Elephant', 'Frog'],
            item3: ['Goat', 'Hotel', 'Indian']
        },
```

Comment: I know it was very unusual to have this kind of format but it is currently being generated from the app. I can only import/load it to get the values. Is there a way how to get these array values?

Comment: Yes, you can always import that function, and afterward just call it, and you will be able to get the data.

Comment: @AndrejMirkovic — The "config file" is trying to **call** the `define` function, not create it. If you're going to recommend importing it then you need to state where to import it from.

Comment: @AndrejMirkovic — "so you just make it like this" — Your other recommendation isn't valid JavaScript or valid JSON.

Comment: How should I know his file system management to tell him where should he import it from exactly?

Comment: If its possible to call directly the define() function, how do I start with it?

Comment: @ArvinSalvador — He doesn't have a define function in the first place.